# How tell which jdk contains which versions of JAX-WS

Tags: jaxb, jax-ws, java

There's a fix in one of the more recent versions of JAXB (2.2.1). I'm trying to determine if that's included in a recent update to Java 6. Is there a way to tell which which versions of a JVM/JRE/JDK contain which versions of JAX-WS/JAXB?

Looking at Sun/Oracle's site, I can view the [release notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/releasenotes-136954.html) for the latest versions of Java SE 6, but I can't tell which versions of the XML libs are included. I guess I could download the latest JDK and run 'xjc -version', but there should be a better way (esp. if it was added in a previous release - I don't want to keep downloading JREs to tell which was the first with the version of JAXB I'm interested in).

Comment: Still looking for a general way to know which JDK/JREs include which versions of JAXB (without having to download each/specific JDK and querying it).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To my knowledge, libraries are not upgraded on each released of the JDK/JRE, except in major versions.  Even then, I don't think they cross the minor-version line.

And, to answer your unwritten question, this is the output from `xjc -version` on JDK 1.6.0_24:

```
xjc version "JAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6"
JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, (build JAXB
2.1.10 in JDK 6)
```

2.1.10 was released on February 6th, 2009, which was updated in Java 6u14.

Comment: As a side note, I revised this answer when I checked when JAXB was added to Java.  Having said that, I don't think we'll see 2.2.x in Java 6.

Comment: Thanks for checking v24. This (outdated) page shows that 6u3 contained 2.0.3 so they have updated in this manner before: [Which JAXB RI is included in which JDK?](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Which_JAXB_RI_is_included_in_which_JDK_.html) But you may be right that 2.2.X won't be included in Java6.

Comment: @CincinnatiJoe: You got lucky, as I just installed JDK 1.6.0_24 yesterday. :P